# ngIf does not update my template

Tags: angular

I have the following Component in Angular2 that, receives an array as an input and call to a service to get, for each entry in the array, the Latitude and Longitude of each entry by calling to a service (which returns a Promise)

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit  {

    @Input() players: Player[] = [];
    locations: LatAndLon[] = [];
    isBusy: boolean = true;


    constructor(
        private myService: MyService,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        for (let player of this.players) {
            this.myService.getLatAndLon(player.address).then(latAndLon => {
                this.locations.push(latAndLon);
                this.finishLoading();
            });
        }

    }

    finishLoading(): void {
         this.isBusy = this.players.length != this.locations.length;
    }
    ...
}
```

So, in the **ngOnInit** method I try to get all the data from my service. Then, I want to show it in my template, but, I have to wait until I "resolve" all the service calls.

For that, I created a variable `isBusy` that check whether all the data is available or not. I try to update `isBusy` every time I call to the service (maybe you have a different and better approach, if so, please let me know).

Then, I have the following template:

```
<div *ngIf="!isBusy">
....
```

But, nothing is shown, despite the fact that if I print the values of the locations array, I can see that everything is right, any clue?

Comment: If one of the requests fail, you will never get anything shown. Maybe that happens? If you output `isBusy`, is this set as you expect?

Comment: Hi, I checked it and all the requests are good, and isBusy is set to false at the end.

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example, in a plunkr, that reproduces the problem. Note that the code most probably doesn't do what you want it to do, since there is no guarantee that the promises are resolved in the good order. You should use Promise.all(), or stroe the LatLon in the player itself.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier if you convert your input array into an observable stream:

```
ngOnInit() {
  let source = Observable.from(this.players)
    .concatMap(x => Observable.fromPromise(this.myService.getLatAndLon(x)));

  let subscription = source.subscribe(
    x => this.locations.push(x),
    error => console.log('Error ', error),
    () => this.isBusy = false
  );
}
```

Note: Use `concatMap` if you need your location array to preserve the order of your input array. If this is not needed, you can use `flatMap`.

Here's documentation about bridging Observables and Promises:

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/promises.md

I hope this helps.